# Passthrough ports in a ESB cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

From the carbon docs

Non-blocking HTTP/S transport ports: Used to accept message mediation requests. If you want to send a request to an API or a proxy service for example, you must use these ports. ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file.
8243 - Passthrough or NIO HTTPS transport
8280 - Passthrough or NIO HTTP transport

But in a cluster scenario, 1 MGR and 2 WRK where I'm supposed to send a request ? 
To the MGR ?
To one of the WRK ?

According to the documentation thos port are not load balanced.

Thank to anyone that may clarify

Answer (score 0):

Proxy and API requests are served by Worker nodes. Manager nodes are there to access UI and deploy artifacts only.

If you have 2 worker nodes, you can/should have a loadbalancer in front of them.